# TypeScript 2.4: 'Class LocalizationService incorrectly implements interface ILocalizationService<LocalizedStrings>'

Tags: typescript

I'm facing some issues due to upgrading my TS version.
Before upgrade I had TS 2.3.3 and it worked without any problems, so by requirements I upgraded to TS 2.4 and this version gave me several issues.

I have the following class:

```
module DemoSample.Localization {
    export class LocalizationService implements someNamespace.Localization.ILocalizationService<LocalizedStrings> {
        constructor(private _localizationService: someNamespace.Services.ILocalizationService) {
        }
        load(): JQueryPromise<ILocalizedStrings> {
            var result = $.Deferred<ILocalizedStrings>();
            ...some dummy logic
            return result.promise();
        }
    }
}
```

Implements an interface that has a generic type

```
declare module someNamespace.Localization {
    interface ILocalizationService<T> {
        load(): JQueryPromise<T>;
    }
}
```

And the type specified:

```
module DemoSample.Localization {
    export class LocalizedStrings extends someNamespace.Localization.LocalizedStringsBase implements ILocalizedStrings {
        constructor() {
            super("Test Application");
        }
        ...another dummy logic
    }
}
```

So I'm getting the following errors:

- `Class LocalizationService incorrectly implements interface ILocalizationService<LocalizedStrings>`
- `Types of property load are incompatible.`
- `Type '() => JQueryPromise<ILocalizedStrings> is not assignable to type () => JQueryPromise<LocalizedStrings>'.`
- `Type 'ILocalizedStrings' is not assignable to type 'LocalizedStrings'`

So I was researching about breaking changes from version 2.4 but I'm not found some information about interfaces with generic types.

The breaking changes has a mention about **Stricter checking for generic functions** https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#stricter-checking-for-generic-functions

Do I must assume that new "feature" is strict on generic interfaces or classes too?

I'm new on TypeScript so I will be very grateful with your help.

Regards

Comment: It's probably [this change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#stricter-variance-in-callback-parameters), since `Promise<T>` and `Promise<U>` have different callback types in `then()` when `T` is not the same as `U`.  You haven't necessarily given enough code to verify that though.  Ideally you'd provide a [mcve] someone can drop into something like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and see what you're seeing.  I'm also confused why you are upgrading to TS2.4 now when TS3.5 is out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, yes I was worndering why 2.4 but we don´t know why too, it´s about customer requirements.. and thanks for the suggestion about how to ask here, we already solved this issue I will answer this question myself and hope this help someone

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the **strict generics type checkings** (introduced on TS 2.4) is affecting this code block since we are specifying that the ILocalizationService interface and its function load() must be the same type, so we are putting two diferent types on them, a class as the interface type and a interface as the load() function type, so both aren't same type and the check fails.

So the workaround that fixes it was putting the **LocalizedStrings** class as the same type for both since this class already implements the interface that load() function was using before, and both are the same type now and the check is success.

```
module DemoSample.Localization {
    export class LocalizationService implements someNamespace.Localization.ILocalizationService<LocalizedStrings> {
        constructor(private _localizationService: someNamespace.Services.ILocalizationService) {}
        load(): JQueryPromise<LocalizedStrings> {
            var result = $.Deferred<LocalizedStrings>();//the same class as the type
            ...some dummy logic
            return result.promise();
            }
    }
}
```